# Compiling C++ code from vim

Tags: c++, linux, vim, terminal

My .vimrc file looks like that:

```
set exrc
set secure
set number
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
set autoindent
set background=dark
set vb t_vb=
set colorcolumn=110
highlight Pmenu ctermfg=2 ctermbg=0 guifg=#ffffff guibg=#0000ff
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=darkgray
autocmd CompleteDone * pclose
compiler g++
```

But, when I am opening some C++ files, I see such a message:

```
E666: compiler not supported: g++
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Use `:compiler` to get a list of available compilers.

Comment: Okay, there is gcc compiler, but there is no g++ compiler. How can I add it?

Comment: @Andrew `apt-get install g++`?

Comment: No, I have installed g++ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:compiler` command selects a *compiler plugin*; there's one named `gcc`, but none named `g++`. That's the `E666` you get.

You can obtain a list of all installed compiler plugins by typing `:compiler` followed by `<C-D>` (lists all) or `<Tab>` (completion).

---

Note that compilation of C/C++ source code is usually done via `make` (or equivalent build tool); a simple `g++` invocation is just for turning a single C/C++ source code file to an object file; you're missing a lot of infrastructure there.

There's the [SingleCompile plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3115) (which supports `g++`, among many others), though.

---

Writing a new compiler plugin isn't much work; you essentially only need to define `makeprg` and `errorformat`, see `:help write-compiler-plugin`.